# Func delegate working unexpectedly

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming, extension-methods

I have an extension method for the IEnumerable interface which takes a delegate of type `Func<T, bool?>` as the argument:

```
 public static bool? ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool?> func)
 {
        bool? commandSuccessful = true;

        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            var rv = func(element);

            if (rv == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (rv == false)
            {
                commandSuccessful = false;
            }
        }

        return commandSuccessful;
  }
```

But the same extension method can still be used when the func's signature is `Func <T, RuntimeDetails, bool?>`:

```
RuntimeDetails lastRuntimeDetails = null;
var startCommandSuccessful = 
    activeConfiguration.Applications.ForEach( 
                        _ => PrepareRuntimeDetailsAndDownload( _ , ref lastRuntimeDetails));



private bool? PrepareRuntimeDetailsAndDownload(Application configurationApplication, 
            ref RuntimeDetails lastRuntimeDetails)
        {...}
```

I am confused and joyful at the same time. Why did it work? If it didn't work I have no idea how I would write the extension because the `RuntimeDetails` parameter is unknown in the extension method.

Comment: why is the question downvoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong

```
_ => PrepareRuntimDetailsAndDownload(...)
```

**is not** a `Func<T, RunTimeDetails, bool?>`! It *is* a `Func<T, bool?>`, it takes one argument of type `T` and returns a `bool?`. You don't pass `lastRuntimeDetails` as argument. It's only a [*closure*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/17/what-are-closures/).

Comment: So the func I am passing to the extension method is not the `PrepareRuntimeDetailsAndDownload` function but the anonymous lambda...

Comment: @meonstackexchange exactly.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda `_ => PrepareRuntimeDetailsAndDownload( _ , ref lastRuntimeDetails)` takes one parameter (`_`) of type `T` and produces a result of type `bool?`. Therefore it's type is `Func<T, bool?>`, not `Func<T, RuntimeDetails, bool?>`.